# Reading HTML content from UIWebView after editing it

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to load an HTML page that has text fields into a webview, edit the text in text fields and then get the HTML data in that webview.

I'm using this code to load the page:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"htm"];
NSData* xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[web loadData:xmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

And this code to get the content and set it again in the webview:

```
NSString *myText = [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.all[0].innerHTML"];
data = [myText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[web loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

The problem is that the text I inserted in the text field is not being returned from the webview.

I tried `document.body.innerHTML` and `document.body.outerHTML`, they all return the HTML page data the way I loaded it.

Is there anyway to get the HTML page data that includes text I inserted there?

Comment: If there's a submit button that would POST the entries back again, are you not able to intercept this call and read the POST data?

Comment: I'm trying to do this offline. To save the data and then submit it when the connection is back online again. As a workaround, I'm currently reading the text fields using their IDs.

Comment: What we did was implementing the web view delegate method [shouldStartLoadWithRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:). Inside the method you have acces to the get parameters of the URL. You can parse the data and based on the online state do the actual post request or not. Alternatively you could use a JavaScript function to return the `value` (not innerHTML) of the test fields.

Comment: `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` will return the original HTML code that is the page source, and the page source does not actually change when you edit the text field values. As @TorstenWalter says, you need to get the `value` of the fields, not the HTML, then insert them into the HTML code for the page that you have stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. If you are using jquery, you should be able to use an expression that returns the value of your textfield, i.e.:

```
NSString* text = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#myTextFieldId').val();"];
```